# How to use XMLHttpRequest to post File, data to Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

I Have tried to make an Node.js webapp to post data from client to Node.js server use XMLHttpRequest:
Client (all code in ejs File):

```
<body>
  <h1>This is Home Page</h1>
  <input type='text' id='num' value="10"></input>
  <button onclick="hi()"  style="height: 50px, width: 50px"> hi there </button>
</body>

<script>
function hi(){
  var number = {
    value: document.getElementById('num').value
  }
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('POST', '/num', true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(number))
}
</script>
```

and server:

```
app.post('/num', function (req, res) {
  var num = req.body.value
  console.log("server reviced... ", num)
  console.log(num)
  return res.end('done')
})
```

Then, here is my example:

[my webapp example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dZEK.png)

After i clicked to button to post data, i got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at D:\...\Nodejs\XMLHttpRequest\index.js:24:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\...\Nodejs\XMLHttpRequest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

How to fix it? Thanks for help!

Comment: Set your `Content-Length` header in your browser code or use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in place of XHR. Then use [`app.use(express.urlencoded())`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) as you set up express, to get the POST body.

Comment: I'm a newBee. Thanks O. Jones a lot for help, i fixed my bug. i put to my project: `// for parsing application/json app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/xwww- app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`; And that's work!!